# PostgreSQL: Combine regexp_split_to_table results into one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working with a database and trying to get all the individual words that appear in 3 columns. I am SELECTing from columns `title`, `description`, and `manufacturer`, and using `regexp_split_to_table` to split into words on whitespace/punctuation/other relevant delimiters.

Right now I'm displaying 3 different columns, each with the results from `title`, `description`, and `manufacturer` respectively, but I want one column `word` where the results of all columns appear.

Here's what I have so far:

```
 SELECT regexp_split_to_table(trim(lower(title)), '\s+|[.()?<>!""@#$%&*;-_\/]+|[0-9]+|([0-9]+x{1}[0-9]+|[0-9]+|([0-9]+x{1}[0-9]+)')
        AS word1,
        regexp_split_to_table(trim(lower(description)), '\s+|[.()?<>!""@#$%&*;-_\/]+|[0-9]+|([0-9]+x{1}[0-9]+|[0-9]+|([0-9]+x{1}[0-9]+)')
        AS word2,
        regexp_split_to_table(trim(lower(manufacturer)), '\s+|[.()?<>!""@#$%&*;-_\/]+|[0-9]+|([0-9]+x{1}[0-9]+)\s+|[.()?<>!""@#$%&*\/]+|[0-9]+|([0-9]+x{1}[0-9]+)')
        AS word3
FROM amazon
LIMIT 500;
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of regex XD  I recommend creating a temp field to combine the results into one.

Comment: Please add a small data sample, including required results,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  regexp_split_to_table (title||' '||description||' '||manufacturer,'[^a-zA-Z]')

from    amazon
```